# UIActivityIndicatorView not show at UItableViewcell

Tags: ios, uiactivityindicatorview

in  the

```
(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if(indexPath.row==[self.peopleDataController countOfList]){

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"LastMoreCell"; 
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;
    moreButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(140, 2, 42, 42)];

    [moreButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"more.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [moreButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showMoreRows:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [cell addSubview:moreButton];
    return cell;
}
 }


-(void) showMoreRows:(id)sender {

    MyAuraAppDelegate *delegate = (MyAuraAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
refreshlast = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];

refreshSpinner.hidesWhenStopped = YES;

refreshlast.center = CGPointMake([[sender superview] superview].bounds.size.width / 2.0f, [[sender superview] superview].bounds.size.height / 2.0f);
[sender setHidden:YES];

[[sender superview].superview addSubview: refreshSpinner];
[refreshlast startAnimating];

    dispatch_queue_t dloadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("People refresh", NULL);
    dispatch_async(dloadQueue, ^{

        if ([[[GlobalVariable sharedInstance] peopleList] count] >0) {

            _peopleDataController = [_peopleDataController initPeopleListWithCoordinate:delegate.locationCoordinate2D auraId:delegate.myToken offset:0];


            NSLog(@"eerrrr %d",_peopleDataController.peopleList.count);

            //     _peopleDataController.peopleList=[[GlobalVariable sharedInstance] peopleList];
            for (int i=0; i< [_peopleDataController.peopleList count]; i++) {
                [[[GlobalVariable sharedInstance] peopleList ] addObject:[_peopleDataController.peopleList objectAtIndex:i]];                
            }

            _peopleDataController.peopleList =[[GlobalVariable sharedInstance] peopleList] ;
            NSLog(@"eerrr33r %d",_peopleDataController.peopleList.count); 
        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{  
            [self performSelector:@selector(addItem) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];
        });  
    });
    dispatch_release(dloadQueue);
```

}

but my  `UIActivityIndicatorView` refresh last  not show,can you give me some clue?

Comment: Hum I don't even want to read your code. I did it but ... It's a mess ! BTW, are you using ARC ?
Well, your application design looks bad. You should really reconsider it.
For your problem you're using `refreshlast` but you never add it to a view ?

Comment: thank you for your answer, if i must add the refresh last to a view,why not add to the cell?

Comment: Why don't you subclass UITableViewCell and add your indicator to it ?

Comment: you can see my post  answer,i have add the  refresh last  to the system cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found my mistake is :[sender superview].superview  is the tabview not the tableviewcell 
so last i modify my code:

```
-(void) showMoreRows:(id)sender {

UIButton *button=(UIButton*)sender;
    MyAuraAppDelegate *delegate = (MyAuraAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
refreshlast = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];

refreshSpinner.hidesWhenStopped = YES;

UITableViewCell *lastcell=(UITableViewCell*)[button superview];

refreshlast.center = CGPointMake(lastcell.frame.size.width / 2.0f, lastcell.frame.size.height / 2.0f);
NSLog(@"ddd %f",lastcell.frame.size.height);
[button setHidden:YES];

[lastcell addSubview:refreshlast];
[refreshlast startAnimating];

    dispatch_queue_t dloadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("People refresh", NULL);
    dispatch_async(dloadQueue, ^{

        if ([[[GlobalVariable sharedInstance] peopleList] count] >0) {

            _peopleDataController = [_peopleDataController initPeopleListWithCoordinate:delegate.locationCoordinate2D auraId:delegate.myToken offset:0];


            NSLog(@"eerrrr %d",_peopleDataController.peopleList.count);

            //     _peopleDataController.peopleList=[[GlobalVariable sharedInstance] peopleList];
            for (int i=0; i< [_peopleDataController.peopleList count]; i++) {
                [[[GlobalVariable sharedInstance] peopleList ] addObject:[_peopleDataController.peopleList objectAtIndex:i]];                
            }

            _peopleDataController.peopleList =[[GlobalVariable sharedInstance] peopleList] ;
            NSLog(@"eerrr33r %d",_peopleDataController.peopleList.count);




        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{  


            [self performSelector:@selector(addItem) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];
        }); 


    });
    dispatch_release(dloadQueue);
```

}